# Construct a topologically $\infty$-dimensional separable metric space.

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces

But don't assume knowledge of any topological dimension theory. Here is a specific approach (an open problem):

Does there exist a separable metric space $X$ such that the following two conditions hold:

- $|X|\ge 2$;
- for every closed   $A\subseteq X$   such that   $X\setminus A$   is disconnected, there exists   $Y\subseteq A$   homeomorphic to   $X$;

**?**

(I formulated this question around 1960, perhaps without ever publishing it; I didn't work on it--too bad, since I like this question :-) )

BTW, you're welcome to use any means (including the dimension theory) to construct $X$. If you did it without using dimension theory or fpp for $I^n$ then you'd obtain a new proof of   $\dim I^n\ge n$   and of *fpp* for $I^n$, for every $n$ (it's well known and easy that if this *fpp* holds for every natural $n$, then for arbitrary cardinal $n$ too).

**TERMINOLOGY:**   *fpp* = Fixed Point Property.

Comment: What's *fpp*? ${}$

Comment: fpp = the Fixed Point Property (I'll add this explanation to the formulation of the problem).

Comment: I find this question very confusingly written. In the title you say "$\infty$-dimensional" but not in the text. If infinite dimension is a consequence of your conditions, please indicate that. The text is fragmented (what is the first paragraph for?). You could just say "fixed-point property" in the single place where you use "fpp", so you don't have to explain what the acronym means. Also, it might help if you explain why $I^\omega$ isn't a solution, even if so for a trivial reason.

Comment: Oops, I was reading the second condition wrong, thinking you want a copy of $X$ inside $X \setminus A$. $I^\omega$ obviously is not a solution.

Comment: @A.B.--my bad.

Any space $X$, which satisfies the above 2 conditions (from the question) must be $\infty$-dimensional--think of the Ind definition of the topological dimension.

(The bad luck wants that my first attempt at posting my question ended in a failure; I've encountered a software system difficulty. My first edition was quite extensive. It's hard for me to concentrate on the second edition, when I am a kind of sick of writing about the same again).

Comment: May I edit the question a bit? You can always cancel the changes if you do not like that.

Comment: @A.B.--please (be my guest :-)

Comment: Do we know that Hilbert space $l^2$ is not such a space?  Explain, please.

Comment: I feel that it should not be difficult to disconnect &nbsp; $\el^2$ &nbsp; by a closed subset which does not contain any topological arc (any subspace homeomorphic to $I$). I may come back to this later.

Comment: I see TeX+HTML problems in my comment above. I think that Hilbert Space can be disconnected by a closed subset which does not contain any arc.

Comment: Andrey, you're welcome to edit my question (that's what I meant in my earlier comment, just under yours).)